# Initializing an array with a constexpr?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I wonder if it is possible to initialize an entire array with a constexpr function (with C++ 2011).
Here I have something to illustrate what I want to do :

```
template<unsigned int DIM> const unsigned int MyClass<DIM>::_myVar[2][3] = {
{metaFunction(0, 0, DIM), metaFunction(0, 1, DIM), metaFunction(0, 2, DIM)}, 
{metaFunction(1, 0, DIM), metaFunction(1, 1, DIM), metaFunction(1, 2, DIM)}
};

template<unsigned int DIM> inline constexpr unsigned int MyClass<DIM>::metaFunction(const unsigned int k, const unsigned int n, const unsigned int dim)
{
    return (((n < dim) && (k < n)) ? (1<<(n-k)) : (0));
}
```

Is there a way to initialize myVar with a constexpr without filling the array manually. And if it exists, what would be the syntax for the given example ?

To precise the question a little, I search for a way to fill all values of myVar using a single function call.

Comment: How about an initializer list: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907471/c0x-initializer-list-example)

Comment: What do you mean by "without filling the array manually"? Also, you don't need a `constexpr` here. You would if you were setting the dimensions of `_myVar`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think the question is: How to fill a constexpr array using constexpr functions in a generic way?

Comment: I nice, template-based solution has been already [discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c). However, this depends on the template recursion depth of your compiler. If the limit is reached use the [Boost Preprocessor Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), in particular [`BOOST_PP_ENUM`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531645/array-of-2s-power-using-template-in-c) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the definition of `MyClass` the problem is not quite clear.
I believe anyway that you want to get `MyClass::_myVar` initialized without
code to iteratively fill it with the `MyClass::metaFunction()` values.

You code suggests that `MyClass::_myVar` is a static class member. In that
case your initialization of the member is perfectly good C++11 as it stands.
The following program illustrates (GCC 4.6.3):

```
#include <iostream>

/* MyClass Version 1 */
template<unsigned int DIM>
struct MyClass
{
    static constexpr unsigned int metaFunction(
        const unsigned int k, 
        const unsigned int n,
        const unsigned int dim);

    static const unsigned int _myVar[2][3]; 
};

template<unsigned int DIM> inline constexpr 
unsigned int MyClass<DIM>::metaFunction(
    const unsigned int k, 
    const unsigned int n,
    const unsigned int dim)
{
    return (((n < dim) && (k < n)) ? (1<<(n-k)) : (0));
}

template<unsigned int DIM> const unsigned int MyClass<DIM>::_myVar[2][3] = {
    {   metaFunction(0, 0, DIM),
        metaFunction(0, 1, DIM),
        metaFunction(0, 2, DIM)
    }, 
    {   metaFunction(1, 0, DIM),
        metaFunction(1, 1, DIM),
        metaFunction(1, 2, DIM)
    }
};

template<unsigned int DIM> inline constexpr 
unsigned int MyClass<DIM>::metaFunction(
    const unsigned int k, 
    const unsigned int n,
    const unsigned int dim)
{
    return (((n < dim) && (k < n)) ? (1<<(n-k)) : (0));
}

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    MyClass<3> mine;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            cout << mine._myVar[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This inclines me to think that `MyClass::_myVar` is *not* a static member -
although why this array of integer constants would not be static I am not sure.
If that is the case, then you can initialize the member in the default
constructor using the [uniform initialization provision of C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization):

```
/* MyClass Version 2 */
template<unsigned int DIM>
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    :   _myVar{
            {   MyClass::metaFunction(0, 0, DIM),
                MyClass::metaFunction(0, 1, DIM),
                MyClass::metaFunction(0, 2, DIM)
            }, 
            {   MyClass::metaFunction(1, 0, DIM),
                MyClass::metaFunction(1, 1, DIM),
                MyClass::metaFunction(1, 2, DIM)
            }
    }{}

    static constexpr unsigned int metaFunction(
        const unsigned int k, 
        const unsigned int n,
        const unsigned int dim);

    const unsigned int _myVar[2][3];
};
```

In neither case is the `constexpr` attribute of `metaFunction` actually
necessary for compilation. And if `constexpr` is removed
then `/* MyClass Version 1*/` is also good for C++03.